# MySQL - need to find records without a period in them

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-negation

I've been to the regexp page on the MySQL website and am having trouble getting the query right. I have a list of links and I want to find invalid links that do not contain a period. Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
select * from `links` where (url REGEXP '[^\\.]')
```

It's returning all rows in the entire database. I just want it to show me the rows where 'url' doesn't contain a period. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp matches anything that contains a character that **isn't** a period. So if it contains `foo.bar`, the regexp matches the `f` and succeeds. You can do:

```
WHERE url REGEXP '^[^.]*$'
```

The anchors and repetition operator make this check that **every** character is not a period. Or you can do:

```
WHERE LOCATE(url, '.') = 0
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `.` when it's inside `[]` in a regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c1 FROM t1 WHERE c1 NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: This proves to be the fastest way to do it. Thanks! BTW, I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have 15 reputation yet lol

Answer (score 0):

Using `regexp` seems like an overkill here. A simple `like` operator would do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE url NOT LIKE '%.%
```

EDIT:

Having said that, if you really want to negate `regexp`, just use `not regexp`:

```
SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE url NOT REGEXP '[\\.]';
```